# Spring Boot Application tried parse application.properties like XML file

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, spring-boot, properties

When I try launch application, console displayed XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException for application.properties file.
I couldn't understand why Application tried to read it like XML file. Help me find problem and solve. Thank in advance.

So that console output

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.0.RELEASE)

[2016-12-08 10:18:23.297] boot - 6023  INFO [main] --- Main: Starting Main on aleksey-HP-Notebook with PID 6023 (/home/aleksey/MfWorkspace/magicflex/application/VCAUI/target/classes started by aleksey in /home/aleksey/MfWorkspace/magicflex/application/VCAUI)
[2016-12-08 10:18:23.303] boot - 6023  INFO [main] --- Main: No profiles are active
[2016-12-08 10:18:23.328] boot - 6023  INFO [main] --- XmlBeanDefinitionReader: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [com/dooks/vcaui/server/applicationContext.xml]
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/aleksey/MfWorkspace/magicflex/application/VCA/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/aleksey/MfWorkspace/magicflex/application/VCAUI/war/WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.SimpleLoggerFactory]
[pool-1-thread-1] INFO org.hibernate.validator.util.Version - Hibernate Validator 4.2.0.Final
[2016-12-08 10:18:24.265] boot - 6023  INFO [main] --- AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext: Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@57f23557: startup date [Thu Dec 08 10:18:24 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2016-12-08 10:18:26.859] boot - 6023  INFO [main] --- ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader: Skipping bean definition for [BeanMethod:name=transactionalEventListenerFactory,declaringClass=org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AbstractTransactionManagementConfiguration]: a definition for bean 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionalEventListenerFactory' already exists. This top-level bean definition is considered as an override.
[2016-12-08 10:18:26.871] boot - 6023 ERROR [main] --- SpringApplication: Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 1 in XML document from class path resource [com/mf/spring/configuration/application.properties] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1112)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1101)
    at com.dooks.vcaui.server.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1472)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:994)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:112)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:505)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:841)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:770)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:243)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391)
    ... 21 more
```

I have Spring boot application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run("classpath:/com/dooks/vcaui/server/applicationContext.xml", args);
    }


}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.dooks.vcaui.server, com.dooks, com.mf"/>

    <!-- first, define your individual @Configuration classes as beans -->
    <bean class="com.mf.spring.configuration.VcaConfig"/>
    <bean class="com.mf.spring.configuration.HibernateConfig"/>
    <bean class="com.mf.spring.configuration.LicenseConfig"/>
    <bean class="com.mf.spring.configuration.BeanConfig"/>
</beans>
```

That hibernate configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.dooks", "com.mf"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource(value = { "classpath:/com/mf/spring/configuration/application.properties" }),
    @PropertySource(value = { "/etc/dooks/application.properties" }, ignoreResourceNotFound=true)
})
public class HibernateConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.dooks", "com.mf" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean(destroyMethod="close")
    public DataSource dataSource() throws IllegalStateException, PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClass(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setJdbcUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));

        dataSource.setUser(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(environment.getProperty("c3p0.acquire_increment", Integer.class));        
        dataSource.setMinPoolSize(environment.getProperty("c3p0.min_size", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(environment.getProperty("c3p0.max_size", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setMaxIdleTimeExcessConnections(environment.getProperty("c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setMaxStatements(environment.getProperty("c3p0.max_statements", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setAcquireIncrement(environment.getProperty("c3p0.idle_test_period", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(environment.getProperty("c3p0.timeout", Integer.class));
        dataSource.setTestConnectionOnCheckout(environment.getProperty("c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout", Boolean.class));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}
```

and this application.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/dooks?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8
jdbc.username = alex
jdbc.password = P@ssw0rd
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql = false
hibernate.format_sql = false
c3p0.acquire_increment = 1
c3p0.idle_test_period = 100
c3p0.max_size = 100
c3p0.max_statements = 0
c3p0.min_size = 5
c3p0.timeout = 3600
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout = true
c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections = 60
```

**Edited**

When I tried remove application.properties file, @ResourceSource(s) annotations and write values from file manualy into HibernateConfig, that exception still. Even if I not use Spring Boot and just try take applicationContext.xml by ClassPathXmlApplicationContext. I sure just HibernateConfig used that, but something tried to look at this file.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/applicationContext.xml");

    }
```

Exception

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/mf/spring/configuration/application.properties]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/mf/spring/configuration/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromImportedResources(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:346)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:142)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:677)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:519)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.dooks.vcaui.server.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [com/mf/spring/configuration/application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:330)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: there must be some wild character before the first line, which might not be visible. usually happens when we copy paste it. Either copy paste yml file in notepad and check. or u can remove the first line and rewrite it again manually.

Comment: Zubair, that not solution, but thanks. Look at edited part of question.